# Insert Value into MVC html tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hopefully what I've done below is self explanatory.  However the response.write doesn't write the img between the td tags, instead it writes it to the top of the Html.  I tried to do it without the Response.write but could work out how to do insert @Lnk.FileName into the img tag, anyone able to understand what I'm trying to do and recommend the MVC way of doing it?

```
    @foreach (Games.Models.GameDetail Lnk in Model.oListSpace)
    {
        <h3>@Lnk.Name</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="250px">
                    @if(System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~") +"\\pictures\\games\\" + Lnk.Filename+".jpg") )
                    {
                        Response.Write("<img src=\"/pictures/games/" + @Lnk.Filename + ".jpg\"/>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Response.Write((Server.MapPath("~") + "\\pictures\\games\\" + Lnk.Filename + ".jpg") +"<br/>");
                    }
                    <a href="/games/review/@Lnk.Filename">@Lnk.Name</a></td>
                <td>@Lnk.ShortDesc</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
```

Thanks for any answers in advance.  If duplicate question, please provide link to what you think is the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    @foreach (Games.Models.GameDetail Lnk in Model.oListSpace)
    {
        <h3>@Lnk.Name</h3>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="250px">
                    @if(System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~") +"\\pictures\\games\\" + Lnk.Filename+".jpg") )
                    {
                         <img src="/pictures/games/@(Lnk.Filename).jpg"/>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Response.Write((Server.MapPath("~") + "\\pictures\\games\\" + Lnk.Filename + ".jpg") +"<br/>");
                    }
                    <a href="/games/review/@Lnk.Filename">@Lnk.Name</a></td>
                <td>@Lnk.ShortDesc</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.